# How to change ringer mode to Silent/Ring/Vibrate on click in react-native android application?

Tags: android, react-native, user-profile, ring, silent

I am creating an application for android using react-native.  I need to change the ringer mode to Silent or Ring or Vibrate on click as per request and the ringer mode should have to change for the phone.
How do I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [react-native-ringer-mode](https://github.com/ryhnnl/react-native-ringer-mode), although iOS not supported because of the limitations, it works like a charm on Android.

Install the package.

```
npm install react-native-ringer-mode
```

Add the line below to your `AndroidManifest.xml` since it is required to change mode to or from silent mode.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

And you can use it like this. Code example taken from the package README.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

import {
  useRingerMode,
  RINGER_MODE,
  checkDndAccess,
  requestDndAccess,
} from 'react-native-ringer-mode';

export default function App() {
  const { mode, setMode } = useRingerMode();

  const changeMode = async (newMode) => {
    if (newMode === RINGER_MODE.silent || mode === RINGER_MODE.silent) {
      const hasDndAccess = await checkDndAccess();
      
      if (hasDndAccess === false) {
        // This function opens the DND settings.
        // You can ask user to give the permission with a modal before calling this function.
        requestDndAccess();
        return;
      }
    }

    setMode(newMode);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Silent" onPress={() => changeMode(RINGER_MODE.silent)} />
      <Button title="Normal" onPress={() => changeMode(RINGER_MODE.normal)} />
      <Button title="Vibrate" onPress={() => changeMode(RINGER_MODE.vibrate)} />
    </View>
  );
}
```